# Numpy vectorize as a decorator with arguments

Tags: python, numpy, decorator, python-decorators

I tried to vectorize (agreed, not the most efficient way to do it, but my question is rather on the decorator use) the following function

```
 @np.vectorize
 def diff_if_bigger(x, y):
     return y - x if y > x else 0

 x = np.array([5.6, 7.0])
 y = 8

 diff_if_bigger(x, y)
 # outputs array([2, 1]) which is not what I want
```

**EDIT**: After restarting IPython, the output was OK.

Can anyone explain why the result of `diff_if_bigger` got tansformed into an array of `np.int` even if the first argument x is here an aray of `np.float`, contrarily to what's in the doc????

Now, I want to force a float output, so I did this

```
 @np.vectorize('np.float')
 def diff_if_bigger(x, y):
     return y - x if y > x else 0
 # Error !!
 # TypeError: Object is not callable.

 @np.vectorize(otypes='np.float')
 def diff_if_bigger(x, y):
     return y - x if y > x else 0
 # Again error !!
 # TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)


 @np.vectorize(otypes=[np.float])
 def diff_if_bigger(x, y):
     return y - x if y > x else 0
 # Still an error !!
 # TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

By the way, even this

```
 vec_diff = np.vectorize(diff_if_bigger, otypes=[np.float])
```

doesn't work!!! So what's going on??

**EDIT**: In fact, the latter worked after I restarted IPython.

So after my previous two edits, my question is now twofold:

1- How can I use np.vectorize as a decorator with arguments?

2- How can I clean IPython state?

Comment: @seberg, no, you're telling nonsense ..

Comment: Look, you really don't answer specifically any of my questions .. Have you even tried to run the code bits I posted??? Have you looked at the vectorize help??

Comment: Sorry, but maybe you should give better errors descriptions, it is a bit hard to diagnose like that. 1. All of your examples actually work (but the decorator ones giving a type, which cannot). 2. Your first example could fail, if you gave a different input before that input. 3. The last vectorize call on a function that is already vectorized makes no sense, so maybe that is your ominous "doesn't work".

Comment: Unless, you are using a numpy version that is much much older then 1.6.1.

Comment: @seberg, your comment about me not doing enough *great* research was offensive even if you deleted it. If I ask questions here on SO, it's after trying things, reading the docs, going through the manuals and so on. I wouldn't even distrurb you with my dumb questions anyway if I was able to do the kind of *great* research you're referring to. In your first comment that you also deleted, you talked about the difference about np.float and np.float_ but I didn't see how it could relate to my problem. Now you also downvoted me, I don't care.

Comment: great, because I did not even downvote :). Quite honestly, it did seem like a possible point, you could have just said: no that is not the reason as well...

Comment: @seberg Still, I don't get your point about np.float_. After checking the doc strings, it seems np.float() and np.int() are conversion functions. Now in a np.array doc example, one can see np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=complex) where complex is also a conversion function so I would tend to think that there would be no problem using np.float for np.vectorize's otypes

Comment: There is not for vectorize, but it was not implausible to me. `np.float is float`, it is the built-in Python type, usually numpy just converts that to `np.float_`/`np.float64` (which is the same), but there are some (rare) exceptions, where `float` fails since it does not have `.char` attribute, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Works for me:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> @np.vectorize
... def diff_if_bigger(x, y):
...      return y - x if y > x else 0
...
>>> diff_if_bigger(np.array([5.6,7.0]), 8)
array([ 2.4,  1. ])
```

Note that `np.vectorize` isn't really meant as a decorator except for the simplest cases. If you need to specify an explicit `otype`, use the usual form `new_func = np.vectorize(old_func, otypes=...)` or use `functools.partial` to get a decorator.

Note too that `np.vectorize`, by default, gets its output type from evaluating the function on the first argument:

> The data type of the output of `vectorized` is determined by calling the function with the first element of the input.

So, you should pass `float` and return `float` if you want to ensure that it infers `float` as the output dtype (e.g. use `else 0.0` and pass `y = 8.0`).

Comment: My numpy version is 1.6.1 .. and I don't get the same behavior as you report but the one I mentioned in my post. In my cas, the first input x is an array of `np.float`'s so why do I get an array of `np.int` at the end?? But worse, as I mentioned in my OP, I got errors even if I didn't use np.vectorize as a decorator!!

Comment: it is no the first "input" that matters, but the first "output" and 0 is not a float.

Comment: @nneonneo I'm afraid that the behavior I got was because of the internal state of my IPython session. But then, I can't figure out why that session got corrupted to the point where the np.vectorize didn't behave like announced in the docs.

Comment: @seberg the doc says that the output depends on the type of the **first input** ...